# Issues querying Access '07 database in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, ms-access

I'm doing a .NET unit as part of my studies.  I've only just started, with a lecturer that as kinda failed to give me the most solid foundation with .NET, so excuse the noobishness.

I'm making a pretty simple and generic database-driven application.  I'm using C# and I'm accessing a Microsoft Access 2007 database.

I've put the database-ish stuff in its own class with the methods just spitting out OleDbDataAdapters that I use for committing.  I feed any methods which preform a query a DataSet object from the main program, which is where I'm keeping the data (multiple tables in the db).

I've made a very generic private method that I use to perform SQL SELECT queries and have some public methods wrapping that method to get products, orders.etc (it's a generic retail database).

The generic method uses a separate Connect method to actually make the connection, and it is as follows:

```
private static OleDbConnection Connect()
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(
        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Temp\db.accdb");
    return conn;
}
```

The generic method is as follows:

```
private static OleDbDataAdapter GenericSelectQuery(
    DataSet ds, string namedTable, String selectString)
{
    OleDbCommand oleCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbConnection conn = Connect();
    oleCommand.CommandText = selectString;
    oleCommand.Connection = conn;
    oleCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adapter.SelectCommand = oleCommand;
    adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    adapter.Fill(ds, namedTable);

    return adapter;
}
```

The wrapper methods just pass along the DataSet that they received from the main program, the namedtable string is the name of the table in the dataset, and you pass in the query you wish to make.

It doesn't matter which query I give it (even something simple like SELECT * FROM TableName) I still get thrown an OleDbException, stating that there was en error with the FROM clause of the query.  I've just resorted to building the queries with Access, but there's still no use.  Obviously there's something wrong with my code, which wouldn't actually surprise me.

Here are some wrapper methods I'm using.

```
public static OleDbDataAdapter GetOrderLines(DataSet ds)
{
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = GenericSelectQuery(
        ds, "orderlines", "SELECT OrderLine.* FROM OrderLine;");
    return adapter;
}
```

They all look the same, it's just the SQL that changes.

Comment: Usually, I put my connections into a `using` block to ensure closing. Seems you do not close them at all?!?

Comment: One quick thought... Have you tried running the same queries against the db directly inside Access?

Comment: @UweKeim I didn't even know about `using` in C#.  This is the lack of proper foundation I'm talking about.

As for the issue, turns out that just putting square brackets around the table name fixes absolutely everything.  Everything works fine inside of Access, so I have no idea.  I'll officially answer the question when I'm actually able; given my reputation I can't do it for another six hours.

Comment: If square brackets fix the problem, you either have a key word or a space. Some words are key outside of Access, but can be handled by the query window in Access.

Comment: Suspect 1: Do you have a table called "order"? Order is a keyword... the easiest thing is to rename the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square brackets seem to have fixed the problem.  Turns out I was using a keyword.  Hmph.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something more simple to see if you have connectivity to the table you are looking for. Something like

```
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  using (OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection
         (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Temp\db.accdb"))
            {
            myConnection.Open();
            OleDbDataAdapter myAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT OrderLine.* FROM OrderLine;, myConnection);
            myAdapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
            myAdapter.Fill(ds);               
            }
```

Then from there check to see if stuff is in ds with

```
  ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count()
```

This will actually show you if you are hitting the DB and getting results. From there you can make it more elegant